# Escaping single and double quotes in a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, escaping

How can I escape single and double quotes in a string?

I want to escape single and double quotes together. I know how to pass them separately but don't know how to pass both of them.

e.g: `str = "ruby 'on rails" " = ruby 'on rails"`

Answer (score 101):

My preferred way is to not worry about escaping and instead use `%q`, which behaves like a single-quote string (no interpolation or character escaping), or `%Q` for double quoted string behavior:

```
str = %q[ruby 'on rails" ] # like single-quoting
str2 = %Q[quoting with #{str}] # like double-quoting: will insert variable
```

See https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Strings and search for `% strings`.

Comment: It gives quoting with ruby 'on rails\" , i do not require that extra \

Comment: The escaping is shown only when you `inspect` it. Try to `puts` it instead.

Comment: For string variable, escape double quotes: value.gsub('"', '\"')

Answer (score 38):

Use backslash to escape characters

```
str = "ruby \'on rails\" "
```

Answer (score 30):

Here is a complete list:

[image]

From http://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex10.html

Answer (score 23):

You can use Q strings which allow you to use any delimiter you like:

```
str = %Q|ruby 'on rails" " = ruby 'on rails|
```

Comment: I have search bar and parsed this "sdasd" "fsd" and its gives me = Q|sdasd"

Answer (score 7):

```
>> str = "ruby 'on rails\" \" = ruby 'on rails"
=> "ruby 'on rails" " = ruby 'on rails"
```

Answer (score 7):

I would go with a [heredoc](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents) if I'm starting to have to worry about escaping. It will take care of it for you:

```
string = <<MARKER 
I don't have to "worry" about escaping!!'"!!
MARKER
```

MARKER delineates the start/end of the string. start string on the next line after opening the heredoc, then end the string by using the delineator again on it's own line.

This does all the escaping needed and converts to a double quoted string:

```
string
=> "I don't have to \"worry\" about escaping!!'\"!!\n"
```

Comment: Note that a heredoc is a clumsy way to quote small strings. What this question needs is a meta-answer that lists all the quoting options along with their pros and cons.

Comment: Very true, Mark. I should have noted that it's gross to use them on small strings.

Answer (score 7):

I would use just:

`str = %(ruby 'on rails ")`

Because just `%` stands for double quotes(or %Q) and allows interpolation of variables on the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use `%Q[]` in a more complex scenario:

```
  %Q[
    <meta property="og:title" content="#{@title}" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="#{@fullname}'s profile. #{@fullname}'s location, ranking, outcomes, and more." />
  ].html_safe
```

Answer (score 1):

One caveat:

Using `%Q[]` and `%q[]` for string comparisons is not intuitively safe.

For example, if you load something meant to signify something empty, like `""` or `''`, you need to use the actual escape sequences. For example, let's say `qvar` equals `""` instead of any empty string.

This will evaluate to `false`
`if qvar == "%Q[]"`

As will this,
`if qvar == %Q[]`

While this will evaluate to `true`
`if qvar == "\"\""`

I ran into this issue when sending command-line vars from a different stack to my ruby script. Only [Gabriel Augusto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31791519/3543437) worked for me.