# Interpolating Ruby code within quotes within a string

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

I have a string like this:

```
'say "Twenty-five minutes remaining."'
```

How would I interpolate more dynamic content into that message? I already know the approach below doesn't work, as the content is returned literally.

```
'say "#{minutes_remaining} minutes remaining."'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
minutes_remaining = 25
system("say '#{minutes_remaining} minutes remaining.'")
```

String interpolation only works with double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: That took care of it, thank you -- I'd forgotten that key nuance completely.

Comment: That is not what the OP originally wanted. What was wanted is `"say \"#{minutes_remaining} minutes remaining.\""`.

Comment: @sawa: She's happy with the solution. Do you claim to know better what she wanted? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev My comment is based on what the OP wrote in the question. It is written using double quote around the substring, and if the OP is still happy with single quotation, then that shows sloppiness on the OP.

Comment: @sawa, why is that sloppy? I honestly don't understand what your problem is with switching the single quotes and double quotes around. Please explain.

Comment: @Mischa In the first example, the OP has `"Twenty-five minutes remaining."`, which indicates that that part is expected to be literally double quoted. The OP continued to try to use double quotation in `"#{minutes_remaining} minutes remaining."`, but the problem was that interpolation has to be passed on to the entire string, which means the entire string must be double quoted, and that will interfere with the literal double quotes that is needed inside the string. Your answer switched the expected literal double quotes with single quotes. I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: @sawa, you *assume* that that part is expected to be double quoted. You didn't answer my question why it is sloppy. My answer works. What is the problem??

Comment: @Mischa I don't understand what you mean. I did not say your answer is sloppy. I said that if the OP was satisfied with single quotation even though he/she was asking for double quotation, then the OP is sloppy. Your answer works in the sense that it does not return an exception, but it does not give what was asked.

Comment: +1 to @sawa's example as it elucidates the use of interpolating double-quotes within a double-quoted string by escaping the nested double-quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You can also escape the double quotes in your string content, may like this:

```
puts "say \"#{minutes_remaining} minutes remaining.\""
```

related question [Escaping single and double qoutes from a string in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705982/escaping-single-and-double-qoutes-from-a-string-in-ruby)