# How to escape quotation mark properly in this Ruby oneliner

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby one liner that looks like this.

```
ruby -e "File.open('/tmp/foo', 'a') { |f| f.puts(\"Testing \!@\#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\{\}\|:<>\?\") }"
```

It works all fine until I also want to append a quotation mark within the puts() method.

```
ruby -e "File.open('/tmp/foo', 'a') { |f| f.puts(\"Testing \!@\#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\{\}\|:<>\?"\") }"
```

I am not sure what is the proper way to escape it.  Any idea?

Comment: Any of [these ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705982/escaping-single-and-double-qoutes-from-a-string-in-ruby) help?

Comment: I don't think so.  Not in my case in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use %Q{...} or %{} instead of "..." for ruby string, they are equivalent.

```
ruby -e "File.open('/tmp/foo', 'a') { |f| f.puts(%Q{Testing \!@\#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\{\}\|:<>\?\"}) }"
```

or

```
ruby -e "File.open('/tmp/foo', 'a') { |f| f.puts(%{Testing \!@\#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+\{\}\|:<>\?\"}) }"
```