# How to input text to non standard input elements

Tags: watir

I'm faced with a `span` element for text input instead of an `input` box, and I'm struggling to use Watir (Ruby) to enter text. There's no `set` method, there is a `text` method that returns the text fine, but I don't seem to be able to set the text that way.

I've also tried using `span.select` and `span.focus` and then `browser.send_keys` but nothing is input in the field.

```
<div class="UFIAddCommentInput _1osb _5yk1">
  <div class="_5yk2" tabindex="-2">
    <div class="_5rp7">
      <div class="_1p1t">
        <div class="_1p1v">
          Write a reply...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="_5rpb">
        <div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="false" aria-owns="js_3i" class="_5rpu" contenteditable="true" data-testid="ufi_reply_composer" role="combobox" spellcheck="true" title="Write a reply..." id="js_3j">
          <div data-contents="true">
            <div data-block="true" data-offset-key="8c176-0-0" class="_45m_ _2vxa">
              <span data-offset-key="8c176-0-0">
                <br data-text="true">
                </br>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What could I try next? Is there a way to stop front end designers using non-standard elements?

Comment: Hmm, is there javascript magic making this happen? Do you have a sample of the html? Watir is good about supporting valid html5, and not as good at supporting weird developer notions. ;)

Comment: @titusfortner If it's using a span for input, you can bet your bottom dollar they're using javascript magic! :) I've added it to the question, it's really just a bunch of divs with classes, and a span at the deepest point.

Comment: You mentioned trying `browser.send_keys`. Did you also try `span.send_keys`?

Comment: @JustinKo I didn't, but trying it just now I get `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible`, though `exists?` returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to do this. The difficulty for me was to handle the nested quotes.

Two pieces of knowledge I had to figure out first before being able to do this w/ regards to nested strings:

a.) regarding how javascript handles nested quotes: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

b.) on how to deal with nested quotes in ruby: [Escaping single and double qoutes from a string in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705982/escaping-single-and-double-qoutes-from-a-string-in-ruby) (the `%Q` operator lets you set whatever you want to begin and end a string)

```
css_selector = "span[data-offset-key='8c176-0-0']"
b.execute_script(%Q|query="#{css_selector}"|)
b.execute_script("document.querySelector(query).innerHTML='that was tricky'")
```

Looks like the ability to inject JavaScript using procedures such as this enables you to be able to do just about anything Watir can't do otherwise. Good question, this was a learning experience for me too

Comment: Thanks for this, I just got a chance to try this. It's not working on the actual site, but that's likely something else happening on the site. I'll give it a bit more a play around to see what's what and then get back to you.

Comment: @iain yeah it works with the code sample you provided